# Sorting an array from Largest to smallest in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I wanna sort an array from largest to smallest number and make a new array which has it sorted...

so here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
   int size, sum = 0, answer = 0,pos, max;
   int array[size];
  int array2[size];
  cin >> size;

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
    cin >> array[i];
    sum+=array[i];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {

    max = 0;
    pos = 0;
    for (int q = 0; q < size; q++)
    {
      if (array[q] > max)
      {
        max = array[q];
        pos = q;
      }
    }
    array2[i] = max;
    array[pos] = 0;
    
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
    cout << array2[i] << ", ";
   }

 return 0;
 }
```

When I put my input:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

The output I get is:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
```

but I expect it to be 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?`int size; array[size];` is seriously undefined behaviour.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You're creating two arrays using the uninitialized `size`. That's not going to end well.

Comment: `int array[size];` -- Even if `size` was initialized, this is not valid C++ code.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<int> array(size);` instead.

Comment: Which compiler are you using, it looks like the compilation warning level is too low. This shouldn't build without (serious) warnings. (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/MoxWvG985). A compiler is your friend and you should be able to build without warnings.

Comment: Moving the `std::cin >> size;` to before the array declarations, I find your code works. But it depends on a compiler extension to declare the array sizes that way; it is not standard C++.

Comment: So I guess you aren't allowed to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all always initialize a variable when you create it as by default it has some garbage value in C++,

Also you are trying to assign a size variable (as size for an array) that has nothing assign to it yet which will create problems, Secondly you are initializing an array first and then you are taking the size variable from user which is completely opposite of the flow, for creating arrays with dynamic size see [How Dynamic Array works and is implemented in C++](https://www.guru99.com/cpp-dynamic-array.html)

**Updated Code:**

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
     int main()
     {
       int size=0, sum = 0, answer = 0,pos, max;
      cin >> size;
      int array[size];
      int array2[size];
    
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
        cin >> array[i];
        sum+=array[i];
       }
    
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
    
        max = 0;
        pos = 0;
        for (int q = 0; q < size; q++)
        {
          if (array[q] > max)
          {
            max = array[q];
            pos = q;
          }
        }
        array2[i] = max;
        array[pos] = 0;
        
       }
    
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
        cout << array2[i] << ", ";
       }
    
     return 0;
     }
```

Here is the **Output**

[image: Output Of Code]

**Edit:**

As Per @PaulMcKenzie method, the other way which is considered the appropriate one, uses the std::Vector method to initialize a dynamic array in C++, people who use the first method in visual studio might face errors,

**Second Method Updated Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    using namespace std;
     int main()
     {
       int size=0, sum = 0, answer = 0,pos, max;
      cin >> size;
      std::vector<int> array(size), array2(size);
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
        cin >> array[i];
        sum+=array[i];
       }
    
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
    
        max = 0;
        pos = 0;
        for (int q = 0; q < size; q++)
        {
          if (array[q] > max)
          {
            max = array[q];
            pos = q;
          }
        }
        array2[i] = max;
        array[pos] = 0;
        
       }
    
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
        cout << array2[i] << ", ";
       }
    
     return 0;
     }
```

**Second Output**

[image: Output Using Vector Method]

Comment: @FredLarson oops, I have updated the answer now, Thank you for pointing out

Comment: Absolutely no mention of `std::vector` at the website at the link.  Very poor.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie because this is a simple code requiring a simple solution which also works, If you think you have a better answer please do enlighten us by posting your answer in the thread we all are out here to learn. :)

Comment: The "solution" was mentioned in the main comments.  Simply replace the fake dynamic arrays with `std::vector<int> array(size), array2(size);` and `#include <vector>`.  That is hardly any change that would be worthy of a new answer.  Note that your code will fail to compile for users of Visual C++ who come across your answer and try to compile the code.  So you should update your answer to something that will work for all C++ compilers.

Comment: Ok I tested the Vector<int> method and it worked to, I have added this method in the answer too, Thank you for pointing you

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array variable must be a compile-time constant. A user-supplied value at runtime is probably unknowable at compile time.so I recommend using `std::vector` instead of array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    
    int size=0, input=0;
    std::cout << "enter size :";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> vec;

    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < size; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "enter "<<i<< ".input:";
        std::cin >> input;
        vec.push_back(input);
    }

    // Sort the elements of the vector in descending order
    for (const auto& i : vec)
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater <>());

    //Print the elements of the vector
    for (const auto& i : vec)
       std::cout << i << " ,";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
enter size :5
enter 0.input:1
enter 1.input:2
enter 2.input:3
enter 3.input:4
enter 4.input:5
5 ,4 ,3 ,2 ,1 ,
```